Are amalgams HNN-extensions?
I'm studying geometric groups and graphs of groups, and am trying to build intuition. I'm trying to view amalgams and HNN-extensions in the following way, from the HNN extension Wikipedia:

Thus, HNN extensions describe the fundamental group of a self-glued space in the same way that free products with amalgamation do for two spaces X and Y glued along a connected common subspace, as in the Seifert-van Kampen theorem.

which makes me think we may be able to view amalgamated products as two spaces, glued trivially and then self-glued at $H$:
$$
A *_H B \overset{?}{\cong} (A * B) *_H
$$
for subgroups $H \hookrightarrow A,B$. This turns out not to hold in this way: writing the images of an element $h \in H$ as $h$ for that in $A$ and $\bar h$ for that in $B$, we get isomorphisms
$$A *_H B \cong (A * B)/ \langle \! \langle h = \bar h \rangle \! \rangle$$
(where $\langle \! \langle - \rangle \! \rangle$ represents smallest normal subgroups) and for $t$ the stable letter
$$
(A * B) *_H \cong (A * B * \langle t \rangle) / \langle \!\langle ht = t\bar h\rangle \! \rangle
$$
If we quotient out the second by $t$, we get an isomorphism
$$
A*_HB \cong (A*B)*_H / \langle\! \langle t \rangle\! \rangle
$$
but this loses the construction of $A*_HB$ as an HNN extension.
On the topological space level, I'm thinking this can be viewed as $t$ being a gluing separate to that of $H$: so we get an extra 1-cell connecting the spaces generating $A$ and $B$ respectively, which adds a generator of the fundamental group. On the other hand, this generator wouldn't have the $H$ commutativity $ht = t \bar h$ as it would be separate from any 2-cells which would yield such relations.
So I think I'm missing something. Primarily I'm hoping for a different way of gluing the 2 spaces that does lead to showing amalgams are HNN extensions, but I'm also very interested on the interaction of this stable letter and $H$ in the construction above too.

Related

The isomorphism $∗_\cong (∗)∗_$ is wrong. (Try to work out the case when $A=B=H={1}$ to see why.) The two operations (amalgamated free product and HNN extension) are related but more subtly than this.

@MoisheKohan I've added a clarifying sentence saying that I show that this isn't the case. Do you have a better suggestion for my title? It's true that I divulged a bit from that isomorphism, but I'm also wondering if there are other possible HNN constructions of amalgams. How they are related is in some ways what I hope to gain insight into with this question.

Topologically, an amalgam is an application of SVK theorem to the union $X\cup_Z Y$ where $Z$ is path-connected and $\pi_1$-injective in $X$ and $Y$. An HNN extension corresponds to self-gluing of $X$ by identifying two $\pi_1$-injective path-connected subsets $Z_1, Z_2\subset X$. I still do not understand what exactly you are asking in your question.

@MoisheKohan I'm wondering if we can somehow first glue $X$ and $Y$ into some "$XY$" in such a way to then do a canonical self gluing of $XY$ along $Z$ in a way that provides $\pi_1(X) *_{\pi_1(Z)} \pi_1(Y)$ - is there a better way of expressing this question?

A necessary condition for a group $G$ to be an HNN extension is the existence of a surjective homomorphism $G \mapsto \mathbb Z$. The group $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z * \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ is one of many, many examples of amalgamated free products that have no homomorphism onto $\mathbb Z$; so such groups are not an HNN extensions. Your method therefore must necessarily fail for the group $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z * \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$.

@LeeMosher I think this more or less answers the question I asked, in that we can't form all amalgams as extensions so there must be more - if you make this into an answer I'll accept it!

Possibly what you are looking for is: The amalgam $A*_{A'=B'}B$ embeds into the HNN-extension $\langle A*B, t\mid A'=t^{-1}B't\rangle$ via the map $A\mapsto A$, $B\mapsto t^{-1}Bt$. This is how Lyndon and Schupp prove the normal form theorem for amalgams (first prove Britton's lemma and normal form theorem for HNN extensions, then extend to amalgams via this embedding).

Turning my comment into an answer.
For a group $G$ to be an HNN extension it is necessary that there exists a surjective homomorphism $G \mapsto \mathbb Z$. But there exist amalgamated free products which have no such homomorphism. One good class of examples are free products of the form $G =A * B$ where $A,B$ are any two finite groups: for any homomorphism $f : A*B \to \mathbb Z$, the subgroups $f(A), f(B) \subset \mathbb Z$ must both be trivial, so $f$ is the trivial homomorphism.

Of course it's an iff condition. Every group with infinite cyclic quotient with kernel $N$ is HNN extension of $N$.
